# OSQuery: Event publisher not enabled: etw_process_publisher: etw_process_publisher publisher disabled via configuration

Tags: osquery

**osquery.conf** file:

```
{
  // Configure the daemon below:
  "options": {

    "event_publisher": "etw_process_publisher",
    "enable_ntfs_event_publisher": true
    
  },

  "schedule": {
    "chrome_extensions": {
      "query": "SELECT * from users;",
      "interval": 3600
    }
  }
   
}
```

when i run **osqueryd.exe --config_path="C:\Program Files\osquery\osquery.conf"**, i got the following error:
**I0212 13:55:33.071751  8240 eventfactory.cpp:156] Event publisher not enabled: etw_process_publisher: etw_process_publisher publisher disabled via configuration.**

How can i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I can't spin up a windows machine to test, but you probably need:

```
    "disable_events": false
```

You probably also need to configure some `file_paths`

Take a look at https://osquery.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deployment/file-integrity-monitoring/ and https://blog.trailofbits.com/2020/03/16/real-time-file-monitoring-on-windows-with-osquery/

Comment: it didn't work again, when i add "disable_events": false into conf file. Actually problem is related with etw_process_publisher.